# Write audio file after normalisation in AudioKit

Tags: ios, audiokit

I have an array of `AVAudioPCMBuffer` (`[AVAudioPCMBuffer]`) And I would like to export those to one wav file, after normalisation. I'm unable to find a way to do so in AudioKit. Does anyone know how to achieve this?